# How to find a root for a mathematical function using Intermediate value theorem?

Tags: python, function

Accroding to the Intermediate value theorem for a given function F(x),
I'm supposed to write a function, which gets a mathematical function, two numbers a and b , and an error range, and it gives as an output the number x for which the functions' value for it is close to 0 up to epsilon. 
Examples:

```
>>> find_root(lambda x : x - 1 , -10, 10)
1.0009765625 
>>> find_root(lambda x : x**2 , -10, 10)
>>> #returned None
```

This is the code that I wrote so far, I think I'm on the right way, but I can't figure out what to loop over, I don't get the correct answer with this code.
So what should I fix in it?

```
def find_root(f, a, b, EPS=0.001):
    if (f(a)*f(b))<0:
        for i in range(a,b):
            if f(i)<EPS:
                return (i)
    else:
        return (None)
```

Comment: `526667901021` isn't a root of `X - 1` and isn't even in the interval `[-10, 10]`. Can you explain how the procedure should work in words?

Comment: I know, It's supposed to return 1.0009765625, and that's why I posted my question, I don't know what to fix in it!

Comment: If you don't have an idea how the procedure should work, you shouldn't (and can't) fix your code, you should fix the lack of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dichotomy :

```
def find_root(f, a, b, EPS=0.0001):
  if f(a)==0 : return a
  if f(b)==0 : return b
  if f(a)*f(b)>0 : return None
  c=(a+b)/2
  while(abs(f(c))>EPS) :
    if f(a)*f(c)<0 : b=c
    else : a=c
    c=(a+b)/2
  return c
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `lambda x:x**2-3`. Should return something around 1.7, return `None`

Comment: @Dunno If you use the intermediate value theorem, you have to provide `a` and `b` such that `f(a)*f(b)<0`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is this:

```
def find_root(f, a, b, EPS=0.001):
    #assuming a < b
    x = a
    while x <= b:
        if abs(f(x)) < EPS:
            return x
        else:
            x += EPS
```

Result:

```
>>>find_root(lambda x: x-1, -10, 10)
0.9999999999998982
>>>find_root(lambda x: x-1, -10, -2)
None
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, your procedure cannot find the root if the initial values are both positive or both negative.

Here is a suggestion of how to implement it using a binary search, in order to accelerate the process:

```
def find_root(f, a, b, EPS=0.001):
    fa = f(a)
    fb = f(b)
    if fa*fb > 0: # both positive or both negative
        return None
    while abs(fa) > EPS and abs(fb) > EPS:
        c = (a+b)/2.0
        fc = f(c)
        if fa*fc >= 0:
            a = c
            fa = fc
        else:
            b = c
            fb = fc
    if abs(fa) <= EPS:
        return a
    else:
        return b
```

The return value of `find_root(lambda x : x-1, -10, 10)` is 1.0009765625.